# Digilocker requester apis sdk

Tags: microservices, digital, locker

I am trying to integrate digilocker request apis in my mobile app to allow customers update pan automatically. I am looking for a java sdk which can I use in my project

Answer (score 0):

1. Download digilocker [swagger](https://apisetu.gov.in/api_specification_v10/authpartner.yaml)
2. [Generate](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/) api client using swagger.